# Объясните, пожалуйста, кусок кода

Tags: c++, массивы, циклы

Даны два массива A и B размером NxN.

```
    for (Elem=(!Row)?0:(Row-1); Elem<N; B[Row][Elem]=A[Row][Elem], Elem++) 
      cout<<Elem+1<<", ";
     }
```

Проблемы с этой частью `Elem=(!Row)?0:(Row-1)`

Answer (score 4):

Это написан [тернарный оператор](https://purecodecpp.com/archives/554).
Его вид:

```
<Выражение> ? <если истина> : <если ложь>
```

В Вашем случае, если значение `Row` равно нулю, то тогда значение `Elem` равно нулю, иначе значению `Row-1`.

Answer (score 2):

Если `Row` ноль - начать с него, если не ноль - начать с числа меньше на единицу.